# Linux read -s command and string with spaces

Tags: bash

I want to use `read -s fubar` to read in a string without echoing it to the screen.
This works fine when I input a string with no spaces- with spaces, it seems to not work.
How can I store a password that contains spaces this way?
Thanks

Comment: It should work normally, unless there are spaces at the beginning or end. I'd recommend `IFS= read -rs fubar` -- the IFS= prevents trimming whitespace from the beginning and end, and the `-r` tells it to not do weird things with backslashes. But when you use the variable, [you must double-quote it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable).

Comment: That should be an answer @GordonDavisson.  Here are the bash docs for IFS:        IFS    The Internal Field Separator that is used for word splitting after expansion and to split lines into words with the read builtin command.  The default value is ``<space><tab><newline>''.